# How do you insert characters after the first occurrence of a word or phrase in a string?

Tags: php, string

What would be the best way to to insert characters after the first occurrence of a word or phrase in a given string?

e.g.

$var = 'The big brown dog jumped over the fence';

Insert an "s" after dog making it, "The big brown dogs jumped over the fence".

Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a combination of [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php):

```
function str_insert($str, $search, $insert) {
    $index = strpos($str, $search);
    if($index === false) {
        return $str;
    }
    return substr_replace($str, $search.$insert, $index, strlen($search));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/LJIWedZv)

Comment: Great, easy solution! Thanks for putting it in a function and making it reusable. Happy Holidays :)

Comment: @hsatterwhite: You're welcome :) Thanks, happy holidays for you too :)